# how to create moving average function with statistics analysis..?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, time-series, moving-average

```
def adf(ts):

# Determing rolling statistics
rolmean = pd.rolling_mean(ts, window=12)
rolstd = pd.rolling_std(ts, window=12)
#Plot rolling statistics:
orig = plt.plot(ts, color='blue',label='Original')
mean = plt.plot(rolmean, color='red', label='Rolling Mean')
std = plt.plot(rolstd, color='black', label = 'Rolling Std')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('Rolling Mean & Standard Deviation')
plt.show(block=False)

# Calculate ADF factors
adftest = adfuller(ts, autolag='AIC')
adfoutput = pd.Series(adftest[0:4], index=['Test Statistic','p-value','# of Lags Used',
                                          'Number of Observations Used'])
for key,value in adftest[4].items():
    adfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
return adfoutput**
```

Above I created function which calculate MA window 5.
But when I run following code i get error..

```
df['priceModLogMA12'] = pd.rolling_mean(df.priceModLog, window = 5)**
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_mean'
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought we should use

```
rolmean = ts.rolling(window=12).mean()
```

Instead of

```
rolmean = pd.rolling_mean(ts, window=12)
```

Since pd.rolling_mean is deprecated

**EDIT**

Just change

```
rolmean = pd.rolling_mean(ts, window=12)
rolstd = pd.rolling_std(ts, window=12)
```

To

```
rolmean = ts.rolling(window=12).mean()
rolstd = ts.rolling(window=12).std()
```

**EDIT**

If you are talking about this line change it from

```
df['priceModLogMA12'] = pd.rolling_mean(df.priceModLog, window = 5)
```

To

```
df['priceModLogMA12'] = df.priceModLog.rolling(window = 5).mean()
```

Comment: thank you sir , but how do i change my above function, so i can use it @劉炳瓚

Answer (score 1):

rolling_mean is removed in pandas. Instead you should use pandas.DataFrame.rolling and then apply mean(). Take a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html). You can edit it like this:

```
ts.rolling(window=12).mean()
```